# Community Bot "Feedback" Comment Posted but NOT from a Review?

Tags: support, review, community-user

I recently came across [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75790742/10871073) in the "First Answers" review queue (FA). As it is not really in my field, I would *normally* have skipped it but, just as I was about to do so, I noticed that it had the standard, Community-Bot comment generated when a reviewer (in FA) selects one of the "Share feedback" options.

This baffled me. So, I went to check the [post's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75790742/timeline) to see if had already been reviewed and all I saw (at that point) was that it *had* been reviewed but in the "Late answers" queue (from which those Bot-comments can't be generated).

Thus, as part of my preliminary investigations, I completed the FA review, myself, and selected the very same "Share feedback" option that generates that comment – and this (perhaps unsurprisingly) upvoted the existing Bot comment. (Technically, did this mean that the Bot upvoted *its own* comment?)

In that timeline, I can see no action that could have generated the comment (notice that it was posted over an hour before my review); the post has not been edited (I *think* that can cause a post to go back into the FA queue but I'm not sure).

So, now, I am at a loss as to how to explain where that comment originally came from. Any clues from moderators or staff, who can likely see far more details of the post's history? Or has our beloved Community Bot gone rogue, and started to post "feedback comments" of it own volition – without waiting for a human reviewer to ask it to do so?

Comment: My guess: somebody else did (FA) review it, but there was an error while saving the review queue item.

Comment: @Glorfindel Nice try ... but an "error" on the SE Network: Surely that just cannot be!